# tf-random won't install in Docker container

Tags: haskell, docker, cabal, dockerfile

I'm building my own Haskell development base image for Docker. The following chunk of my Dockerfile results in an error (full message follows):

```
ENV LANG en_GB.UTF-8
RUN ["add-apt-repository", "-y", "ppa:hvr/ghc"]
RUN ["apt-get", "update"]
RUN ["apt-get", "install", "-y", "cabal-install-1.20", "ghc-7.8.3"]
ENV PATH ~/.cabal/bin:/.cabal/bin:/opt/cabal/1.20/bin:/opt/ghc/7.8.3/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
RUN ["cabal", "update"]
RUN ["cabal", "install", "cabal-install"]
RUN ["cabal", "install", "happy"]
RUN ["cabal", "install", "alex"]
```

The error is:

```
cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
QuickCheck-2.7.6 depends on tf-random-0.5 which failed to install.
alex-3.1.3 depends on tf-random-0.5 which failed to install.
tf-random-0.5 failed during the final install step. The exception was:
/tmp/pkgConf-tf-random-03817.5: hGetContents: invalid argument (invalid byte sequence)
```

I added the `LANG` argument to my Dockerfile after reading this [issue report on github](https://github.com/haskell/cabal/issues/1883) but it hasn't helped. Are there any other dependencies needed on my container to resolve this?

Comment: I would make sure you are installing `cabal-install-1.20.0.4` - that's the first version which has the patch for ticket #2006 [(link)](https://github.com/haskell/cabal/pull/2006/commits)

Comment: Try running locale-gen with your LANG value as it's argument.

Comment: @MichaelSnoyman yes that was it. If you post this as an answer I'll accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running locale-gen with your LANG value as it's argument.